# Configuring Swagger UI route

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui, laravel-5.7, swagger-php

I want to use swagger to document a laravel API and have users view the app using a similar route to the `petstore.swagger.io`

This are the steps that I have taken using `swagger-php` & `l5-swagger` packages

1. composer require zircote/swagger-php
2. composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger
3. Added `L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider::class,` to config/app.php file
4. Added annotations to BookController
5. Ran the command `php artisan l5-swagger:generate`

Then I added annotations to BookController like this

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title="Laravel Test OpenApi",
 *      description="L5 Swagger OpenApi description",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="menadio1@gmail.com"
 *      ),
 *     @OA\License(
 *         name="Apache 2.0",
 *         url="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
 *     )
 * )
 */
/**
 *  @OA\Server(
 *      url=L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST,
 *      description="L5 Swagger OpenApi dynamic host server"
 *  )
 *
 *  @OA\Server(
*      url="https://projects.dev/api/v1",
 *      description="L5 Swagger OpenApi Server"
 * )
 */

class BookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *      path="/books",
     *      operationId="getBooksList",
     *      tags={"Books"},
     *      summary="Get list of books",
     *      description="Returns list of books",
     *      @OA\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="successful operation"
     *       ),
     *       @OA\Response(response=400, description="Bad request"),
     *     )
     *
     * Returns list of books
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return BookResource::collection(Book::all());
    }
}
```

At this point I don't know what url to use in loading the swagger UI to view the API documentation. This is the only thing holding me back right now in a coding challenge so I am a little bit desperate for help.

Answer (score 6):

Phew...I was able to load swagger UI and view the api documentation using `http://localhost:8000/api/documentation`

I hope this will save someone else ample amount of time when using swagger for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of your project and run this command to generate the docs.

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

Then navigate to http://yourapp.local/api/docs to view your swagger ui

Comment: This is bit that is confusing me `http://yourapp.local/api/docs` Now I am doing this on my local server and in the annotations which I got from the docs, there are two `@OA\Serve` Which of them would I use or do I have to configure one somehwere?